# OnClick event calling a js function and a callback function

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I have an external compiled project(asp.net) that we are using in our code. I dont have access to the code behind, just the .aspx pages.

One of the things Im trying to do is to call two functions from the button in the page.

```
<cc1:ImageButton ID="btnYes" runat="server" OnClick="btnYes_Click" Text="Yes"
                        Width="40px" SkinID="DefaultButton" />
```

Is there a way I can add a JS function and let the OnClick event call both btnYes_Click and my JS function?
something like this? `OnClick="btnYes_Click ; myfunction();"`

I dont have any access to the code behind page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes there is an event called **OnClientClick="JSFunction"** add that to your control. if not then add it from codebehind like **MyControl.Attributes["onclick"] = "JSFunction";**